# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am getting this issue unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

Here is my models.py

```
def _convert(self,from_currency, to_currency, price):
        custom_rate_obj = self.quote.client.custom_rates.filter(currency=to_currency).first()
        if custom_rate_obj is None or custom_rate_obj.exchange_rate in (0, None):
            custom_rate_obj = ExchangeRates.objects.latest('created')
        return custom_rate_obj.convert(from_currency, to_currency, price)

    def get_margin(self):
        if self.cost_price:
            cost_price = self.cost_price
            unit_price = self._convert(self.currency, self.cost_currency, self.unit_price)
            if unit_price:
                return ((unit_price - float(cost_price))/unit_price) * 100
```

How can i solve my issue

Comment: convert `cost_price` to `Decimal` and process i.e. `((unit_price - Decimal(cost_price))/unit_price) * 100`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `unit_price` to `float` as well.

```
 return ((float(unit_price) - float(cost_price))/unit_price) * 100
```

And always use typing in python 3 t avoid such errors.

```
def _convert(self,from_currency: str, to_currency : str, price: float) => float:
```

Comment: i added float to unit_price then i am getting this issue unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'